# How to reduce the size of a crystal report with OLE image and datasets without loosing resolution

Tags: image, crystal-reports, ole, crystal-reports-2008

I am trying to reduce the size of a crystal report , where in I have converted the image from PDF to BMP and then inserted as an OLE object in to the crystal report. In doing so , The color (Black and white) was still rich and the words in the image are clear.

Using CR 2008

However, The crystal report size is increased to more than 8 megs , which is a lot for the report with a single page.

I have searched online on how to reduce the size of the CR , I have found one answer where , Use photoediting tools , the image to GreyScale and add as OLE object , however in doing so , the image resolution has gradually decreased.

I am still looking for a solution where I can decrease the size of the CR to less than 3 megs with out compromising the image quality in the report.

P.S: My first question on StackOverflow. :)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be programming related. General questions about software and photo editing/conversions are best handled elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Do not convert to another format because Crystal manages the image internally as bitmap.

Reduce color depth. For example, convert from full color to grayscale.

Load the rpt in Crystal and go to 
File, Report Options...
And turn on the checkbox for 'Retain Original Color Depth'.

If you need to resize the image, do so outside Crystal. Resizing an image inside Crystal can cause it to consume more memory.

Comment: Thank you. Will try that

Answer (score 0):

I only stumbled across this question as you had Reporting Services tagged (I've now removed that tag from your question). I'm no Crystal Reports person but I suspect most of the file size is in the BMP. BMPs are uncompressed so they are big, especially compare to other file formats.

You should be able to convert to a PNG or JPEG with low compression and this will reduce the size of the image considerably. Play around with different compression levels when saving to see what works best but I would start at about 90%.

If you need a free (Windows) tool where you can set the compression when saving an image, try paint.net ( https://www.getpaint.net/ ) It's completely free, open source and simple.

Comment: Thanks Alan, Will try your solution